# Get Fragments edittext values on Activity button click event

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a viewpager containing 2 fragments and each fragment contains a edittext. When user clicks the button in the activity i need to get the edittext values in the fragments to activity. I referred to this documentation [Communicating with Other Fragments](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html), it is something like when user click the list item within the fragment  i will get the values in the activity.But in my case the button is in activity.Could anyone suggest the right way of doing this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of the `Activity` asking the `Fragment` for data, pass data from `Fragment` to `Activity` (without the need of it to ask).

What I mean is, add a `TextWatcher` interface to the `EditText` and `afterTextChanged()` use an interface (read again http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html)  to pass it to the `Activity`.  When the user press the button, you dont have to retrieve the value from the fragments, cause you already have them, you just have to apply the logic.

For example:

```
// Inside Activity, it should implement FragmentInterface1, FragmentInterface2
private String str1;
private String str2

@Override
public void onFragment1EditTextChanged(String string) {
    str1 = string;
}

@Override
public void onFragment2EditTextChanged(String string) {
    str2 = string;
}

// This is for each Fragment1 and Fragment2, just change the number acordingly
private FragmentInterface1 listener = null;

@Override
public View onCreateView(/*params*/) {

    // inflate the view

    edittext = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.myEditText);
    edittext.addTextWatcher(new TextWatcher() {

        // Any callback works, but i'd go for this one
        public void afterTextChanged(/*params*/) {
            if(listener != null) listener.onFragment1EditTextChanged(edittext.getText().toString());
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    listener = (FragmentInterface1) activity;
}

public interface FragmentInterface1 {
    public void onFragment1EditTextChanged(String string);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your prompt reply Christopher and i have a doubt on your post. How could i extend this if i have more input controls say 3 to 4 edittext and 1 or 2 selectors etc. Would the above logic of placing change event to individual controls is the right way to achieve it?

Comment: Indeed, what I do is put as many parameters on the `onFragment1EditTextChange()` method (obviously, with a diffrent name heheheh) as input views in my fragment

Comment: If you found my post helpful you may wanna consider marking it as the accepted answer so other people would be able to know how did you solve your problem (:

Comment: sorry for late and i could not get it clear from your comment could you give me a sample or elaborate a little.

Comment: Great and very useful answer :) better explanation then original docs.

Answer (score 5):

You can either do it like Christopher Francisco suggested (with TextWatchers) or you could assign IDs to the EditTexts and retrieve their data like this (in the Buttons onClickListener inside the Activity):

```
String editText1Data = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1)).getText().toString();
String editText2Data = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText2)).getText().toString();
....
```

Comment: I searched many times all solutions were to use watcher and listeners!!! you answer is more much simple and clear! Why are other people use that approach ?! Is there any benefits from it?

Comment: Great answer!! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Thank you so much.